# Translation of are you travelers? Ser or estar?

Tags: verbos

I'm currently learning about the ser and estar verbs of the Spanish language and encountered this problem, whose answer confused me; the problems asked me for the Spanish translation of the following sentence:

> Are you travelers?

The answer of it was:

> ¿Sois vosotras viajeras?

And it confused me since being travelers is non-permanent, and I thought it should rather be estar than ser. Why is ser, which is used for permanent things, used instead of estar here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Ser* is not defined for use with permanent things, and *estar* is not defined for use with non-permanent things. (I really wish Spanish teachers would stop teaching that myth).

*Estar* is used for states, which may or may not be permanent (*él está muerto* is fairly permanent, but is contrasted with *él está vivo*) but ser is used for essential attributes, which likewise may or may not be permanent (*él es joven*).  *Ser* is also used with nouns as the object, which *estar* rejects (*estar*, on the other hand, allows adverbs as the manner of being: *estar bien* that *ser* rejects).

In your example, the predicate nominative is *travelers*, which is a noun, and so by definition to render your English sentence into Spanish, **only *ser* can be used**.   Note, however, that using *estar* is perfectly grammatically okay *in this example* because *viajero* is also an adjectiv, but would not be a correct translation, as in English it would mean something akin to *Y'all are on a trip?* or *Y'all are traveling?* (*estar viajero* = *estar de viaje*)

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that in your studies, you've encountered

> ¿Sois vosotras francesas?
>
> ¿Sois vosotras artistas?

This follows that same pattern, where *ser* is like an equals sign in an equation, indicating something existential.

But there is actually a way to use *estar* to ask a similar question:

> ¿Estáis viajando por Europa? | *Are you traveling through Europe?*

I guess you might prefer this, because "traveler" as an existential identification might be a little off-putting.  But at this stage in your studies, it's okay as an exercise.